# Как загрузить скрипт без нажатия на кнопку, JS

Tags: javascript, html, css

Добрый день, пожалуйста помогите 
Как сделать так, чтобы скрипт срабатывал сразу после загрузки страницы, а не при нажатий на кнопку - Пример шаблона здесь - [Образец](https://tympanus.net/Development/SegmentEffect/index5.html)

---

Человеческое Спасибо, только учусь и хотелось узнать

```
            <div class="segmenter" style="background-image: url(img/5.jpg)"></div>
        <h2 class="trigger-headline trigger-headline--hidden"><span>З</span><span>а</span><span>д</span><span>а</span><span>ч</span><span>и</span></h2>
        </h2>
        <div class="bottom-nav">
            <button class="btn btn--trigger">! </button>
        </div>
    </main>
    <script src="js/anime.min.js"></script>
    <script src="js/imagesloaded.pkgd.min.js"></script>
    <script src="js/main.js"></script>
    <script>
    (function() {
        var headline = document.querySelector('.trigger-headline'),
            trigger = document.querySelector('.btn--trigger'),
            segmenter = new Segmenter(document.querySelector('.segmenter'), {
                pieces: 8,
                positions: [
                    {top: 0, left: 0, width: 100, height: 100},
                    {top: 0, left: 0, width: 100, height: 100},
                    {top: 0, left: 0, width: 100, height: 100},
                    {top: 0, left: 0, width: 100, height: 100},
                    {top: 0, left: 0, width: 100, height: 100},
                    {top: 0, left: 0, width: 100, height: 100},
                    {top: 0, left: 0, width: 100, height: 100},
                    {top: 0, left: 0, width: 100, height: 100}
                ],
                shadows: false,
                parallax: true,
                parallaxMovement: {min: 10, max: 30},
                animation: {
                    duration: 2500,
                    easing: 'easeOutExpo',
                    delay: 0,
                    opacity: .1,
                    translateZ: {min: 10, max: 25}
                },
                onReady: function() {
                    trigger.classList.remove('btn--hidden');
                    trigger.addEventListener('click', function() {
                        segmenter.animate();
                        headline.classList.remove('trigger-headline--hidden');
                        this.classList.add('btn--hidden');
                    });
                }
            });
    })();
    </script>
    <hr>
```

Comment: Вы про этот участок `trigger.addEventListener('click', function() {...})` ? Его нужно сразу загрузить?

Comment: да, вроде этот. как можно загрузить скрипт без нажатия на эту кнопку

Comment: Спасибо) за оперативную помощь

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вместо

```
 onReady: function() {
     trigger.classList.remove('btn--hidden');
     trigger.addEventListener('click', function() {
         segmenter.animate();
         headline.classList.remove('trigger-headline--hidden');
         this.classList.add('btn--hidden');
     });
 }
```

Сделайте

```
 onReady: function() {
     segmenter.animate();
     headline.classList.remove('trigger-headline--hidden');
 }
```

Comment: Спасибо большое, вы лучший. Нигде не мог найти ответ))

Comment: @EziS не надо находить ответ, когда он перед вами. Логику включаете и видите, что при клике на кнопку происходят такие то вещи, ищите объявленное событие, и выкидываете наверх его вызовы.

Answer (score 2):

Вместо этого:

```
onReady: function() {
   trigger.classList.remove('btn--hidden');
   trigger.addEventListener('click', function() {
      segmenter.animate();
      headline.classList.remove('trigger-headline--hidden');
      this.classList.add('btn--hidden');
   });
}
```

Вот это:

```
onReady: function() {
   segmenter.animate();
   headline.classList.remove('trigger-headline--hidden');
   trigger.classList.add('btn--hidden');
};
```

Comment: а зачем сначала удалять класс `btn--hidden` с кнопки, а потом сразу же добавлять его обратно?

Comment: @ВадимЛешкевич, исправил

Comment: Спасибо большое и вам, низкий поклон

Comment: @EziS, обращайся! Работаем без выходных и обедов :)

Comment: @ВадимЛешкевич, да уж )